# Cannot iterate through local assets in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to render a ScrollView of images like so:

```
renderIcons()
{
    let activityImages= ['all','boat','camping','climbing','cycling','hiking','running','swimming','yoga'];

    let icons = activityImages.map((image, index) => {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index} onPress={() => {}}>
                <View style={styles.imageWrap}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageDefault}  source={require(`../../assets/activities/${image}.png`)} />
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    });

    return icons;
}
```

And in the render method:

```
render() {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollContainer}
            horizontal={true}
        >
            {this.renderIcons()}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

}

Each of the items in the assets folder is an image with the corresponding file name.

When I run this, I get the error:
Requiring unknown module "../../assets/activities/all.png".

At first I thought it was the incorrect file path, but when I change the source of the image to:
`source={require('../../assets/activities/all.png')} />`, all.png is rendered correctly 8 times (length of array) without any errors. Has anyone run into a similar problem?

EDIT:

The best solution to this is probably a dictionary (github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/282) and [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/282#issuecomment-169165912))

```
const iconsMap = {'burger-menu': require('../img/burger-menu.png')};
// this.props.icon = 'burger-menu'
<Image src={iconsMap[this.props.icon} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to react-native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources), in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />
// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```